# How do I change my mask dynamically on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, masking

I have an input where the user enters a bank account number, and I need to mask it with the syntax "XXXX-X", where the length of the string before the hyphen varies between 4 and 13 digits, and the last digit must be always preceded with an hyphen, which must be added automatically, and not inputed by the user. The way I'm doing it is:

```
<customcontrols:BorderlessEntry Text="{Binding Account}"
        Placeholder="0000000-0"
        Keyboard="Numeric" 
        MaxLength="14"
    <customcontrols:BorderlessEntry.Behaviors>
        <b:MaskedBehavior Mask="XXXXXXX-X" MinLength="6" MaxLength="14" />
    </customcontrols:BorderlessEntry.Behaviors>
</customcontrols:BorderlessEntry>
```

In this code, the length of the mask is fixed, and I need it to be dynamic. Is there an way to do this?

The code I'm already using for masking behavior is similar to [this](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/masked-entry-in-xamarin-forms/)

I've tried some approaches, like changing the text directly in the input through `entry.Text`, but I haven't succeeded

Comment: have you tried changing the `MaskedBehavior` parameters dynamically?

Comment: When you say "the length .. varies", *when* does it vary? Is the length known at the time the control is displayed? If not, when is it known? Whatever code knows what the length should be, is the code that should set the mask.

Comment: @Jason yes, but it didn't work

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it isn't known until the user types it, because it depends on the bank they are choosing to transfer to, as there are different account lengths for different banks

Comment: you could wait and build the control in code once the user selects a bank, or build different controls in XAML and then only display the appropriate one after the bank is selected

Comment: Are you saying that the only way to know is by examining the characters typed by user? If so, then that cannot possibly be represented by a mask, right? Override TextChanged, and put logic there to insert hyphen when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I've done it

```
void AccountEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue) && e.NewTextValue.Length > 4)
        accountEntry.Text = HandleAccount(e.NewTextValue);
}

string HandleAccount(string input)
{
    if (input.Contains("-"))
    {
        input = input.Replace("-", "");
    }

    string result = string.Format("{0}-{1}", input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1), input[input.Length - 1]);

    return result;
}
```